# invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::string&

Tags: c++, methods, reference, initialization, return

```
const string& mtm::RadioManager::getBestSong() const {    
    string& most_popular_song=tmp.getName();    
    most_popular_song = current_song.getName();    
    return most_popular_song;
}

string mtm::Song::getName() const {    
    return this->song_name;
}

class Song {    
    string song_name;

public:

string getName() const;
}
```

I get this error:

> invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::string& {aka std::basic_string&}' from an rvalue of type 'std::string {aka 
>    std::basic_string}'

I can't make it `const string& most_popular_song=tmp.getName();`
because I'm changing it to `tmp.getName();` That returns `string`!
What should I do to get rid of this error?

Comment: What does "becuse I'm changing it to `tmp.getName()`" mean? Changing what exactly?

Comment: @AndreyT I think he meant to say "I'm changing it to `current_song.getName();`"

Comment: sorry forgot the line : const Song& tmp = *(all_songs.begin());

Comment: before: string& most_popular_song=tmp.getName();

Answer (score 2):

Function `getName` does not provide modifying access to the underlying `song_name` field of the class. You can't change `song_name` through `getName` (as written) regardless of what you do. This is the whole point of having `getName` to return a *copy* of the `song_name` field.

For this reason receiving the result by non-constant reference makes no sense whatsoever. You can't change it anyway. And even if you do somehow, it will have no effect on `song_name`.

Under these circumstances, it is completely not clear what you are trying to do by

```
string& most_popular_song=tmp.getName();    
most_popular_song = current_song.getName();
```

sequence and what the point of all these manipulations is.

If you want to be able to modify the `song_name` field, you have to return a *reference* to `song_name` from `getName`

```
string &mtm::Song::getName() const {    
    return this->song_name;
}
```

This will fix your error, but this will basically defeat most of the protection and isolation provided by the `getName` function. What was the point of making `song_name` private, if you immediately and fully expose it to outside world through a nopn-const reference returning `getName` function?

A better idea would be to write a `setName` function and use it to modify the `song_name`, instead of trying to obtain direct reference access to `song_name`.